# Linux - Reset Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Tags: linux, usb

I would need to reset the USB root hub on Linux.
Specifically, each time `lsusb` is executed, the Linux Foundation's root hub with Vendor ID **1d6b** is shown:

```
# lsusb | grep 'Linux Foundation'
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

From `lsusb -t` output, these root hub use drivers **ehci_hcd**, **ohci_hcd** & **musb-hcd**:

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=musb-hdrc/1p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ohci-omap3/3p, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-omap/3p, 480M
```

But these drivers are built-in into the kernel (they were not compiled with the M option)..

But I don't know how to reset this hub.
Is it possible to reset these drivers (or unload and then reload them) from `/sys` fiflesystem ?